# Can't click 1/2 of image link with div tag on top after it's removed

Tags: jquery

I'm making an html game without the canvas (just straight html elements as there are no moving parts) and I have image links that act as abilities. After clicking an ability link I dynamically make a div and absolute position it over the image link. Inside the div it's displaying the cooldown text for that ability. Once the cd is up I .remove() that div tag. However, I can now only click on the top 1/2 of the ability image link now. **The div isn't there as I don't see any text anymore. Anyone have ideas as to why it's acting like the div is still there?**

Also, I set the width and height of the cd div but it doesn't cover the entire ability image link as the top 1/2 is still clickable. I'd prefer it cover the entire image link as another way to prevent the user from clicking the link again while it's on cooldown (I do other client and server side checks to prevent cheating but this would be nice to have also).

This is the cooldown timer that gets called every second. If the action cd is 0 you can see I remove the div (the id of the div is teh action name + "_cd_value"). playerActions is a dictionary where the id is the id of the ability image link. I use this to store other values like cd, etc.

```
// when an ability link is clicked I start it's cd timer every second
$(".action").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    playerActions[id].cdInterval = setInterval(ActionCD, 1000, playerActions[id]);

    var position = $(this).offset();

    // create the cd value div and position it over the ability image link
    $("#divCDHolders").append("<div id=" + id + "_cd_value>" + (playerActions[id].cd / 1000) + "</div>").css({ "position": "absolute", "top": position.top, "left": position.left, "width":"66px", "height":"66px" });
}

function ActionCD(action) {
            action.cd -= 1000;
            var cdName = action.name + "_cd_value";

            // update the cd value
            $("#" + cdName).text((action.cd / 1000));

            // cd is finished
            if (action.cd == 0) {
                // stop this cd timer
                clearInterval(action.cdInterval);

                // reset the cooldown flag so we can click it again
                $("#" + action.name).data("onCooldown", "false");

                // todo: remove the gray semi-transparent image and the count down div over the icon

                // remove the count down number element
                $("#" + cdName).remove();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try inspecting your code with your browser's developer tools; If not this div that you add then remove, there must be something in front of the half of your image that you can't click, that's the best (if not the only) explanation to that problem... That may be any other element you don't think of, or even the position of your image self that is not interpreted the same way it is rendered. Trying to reproduce the issue in a narrowed down jsfiddle might help us to help you, and you might even find the issue in the process...

Comment: So if I do 'show page source' the dynamically added stuff doesn't seem to show up. How can I see the actual page source with the dynamic elements added?

Comment: You definitely need to use developer tools of your browser... try hitting F12. This lets you inspect the DOM, not only the source code, so it includes dynamically generated content aswell as pseudo-elements added through CSS and so on.

Comment: Ah the css wasn't getting added to the new div tag. It was getting added to the divCDHolders div tag and I don't remove that. I keep that as a container for all the dynamic CD divs that I'll be adding/removing throughout the game. I guess I thought append() would return the new div element it appended but I guess not?

Comment: Changed the creation of the cooldown div to the following and it works now: $("#divCDHolders").append($("<div id=" + id + "_cd_value>" + (playerActions[id].cd / 1000) + "</div>").css({ "position": "absolute", "top": position.top, "left": position.left, "width":"66px", "height":"66px" }));